# Adjust estimate precision by sample size

Tags: standard-deviation, meta-analysis

I wish to find comparable SDs/Confidence Intervals for two parameters. 
One parameter has been measured by only one (new) study that reports the standard error. Here, *t* value, sample size and SD are provided.
The other (a correlation coefficient) has been measured by 10 (older) studies, in some as a mean across subjects, in some across all trials (ignoring subjects). The only values available for all studies are n of participants and the mean correlation coefficient; many don't report sufficient information to compute comparable SDs. I believe that all in all, *r* is roughly comparable across the 10 studies in this set.

I don't think I can directly compare the sample SD between subjects in set 1 with the between-study SD in set 2. How can I find comparable CIs/SDs for the two values while somehow controlling for the low sample size in the first study?

I'm not trying to compare the two values using a test (they're physiologically incommensurable), I simply want to look at them on a similar scale.
If I cannot come up with a proper quantification, I would simply be informal and focus on one SD for the 10-study set and two SDs for the one-study set, to reflect that one of them has been estimated "a lot more" precisely than the other.

Comment: what power did the "low sample size" provide for assessing the hypothesis (or hypotheses) in the first study?

Comment: They used a paired *t*-test, 15 subjects. See here for some sample calculations using r.pwr: http://pastebin.com/mR4v2umH

The observed *d* was .7 IIRC.